# load external class placed in vendor folder in controller by composer cakephp3

Tags: soap, wsdl, cakephp-3.0

Actually i want to use soap class in my cakephp application. For that i have created one class file named Wsdl as it call function of wsdl using soap which is placed in Vendor directory.
Now in my ClassController i want to include this class by composer.

> below is my composer.json file code:

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\": "src"
    },
"classmap": [
    "./vendor/WsdlClass/Wsdl"
]
},
```

in my ClassController i am trying to include this file using
useing code:

> use Vendor\WsdlClass\Wsdl;

I am getting error of

> Error: Class 'vendor\WsdlClass\Wsdl' not found

How can i fix this issue of composer??

Comment: I kinda doubt that this is a composer issue, it's more likely that you did something wrong. Please show the contents (namely the namspace and class definition) of your PHP file and its exact filename/path, and make sure that the `use` statement you are showing here is really the exact one that you are using in your code, because the error message suggests something different.

Comment: Hi kinda, sorry for late reply.. you are right actually i am using wrong path in composer.json file. i corrected it to `vendor/WsdlClass` this and now it's loading properly.